# application.properties file in springboot giving null value while accessing from another file

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, annotations, application.properties

I am trying to access values from application.properties file as below code
in rest controller i am trying to create instance of testCon which will return con.

```
@RestController
public class TestCtrl {
     private Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(getClass().getName());
@GetMapping("/test")
    public String test() {
    
        logger.error("in test ctrl");
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String finalJson = null;
        Connection con = null;
        DSConnection dsobj;
        try {
            testCon = new testCon("dbid");
            con = (java.sql.Connection) testCon.getConnection();
            logger.error("in test got con");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            logger.error("error while getting con in welcome2 ctrl");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

In testCon class i have below code which reads value from applicatio.properties and creates connection with properties. Bu when i call above URL it shows null in logger like not able to read from prop file.

```
    
     @Value("${spring.datasource.jndi-name}")
     private String dsName;
     private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(testCon.class);

     public testCon(String dbinstance) throws Exception{
         String username = "";
         String password = "";
        ** logger.debug("title"+dsName);** > here it gives null
```

and application.properties file is

```
server.port=8090
spring.datasource.jndi-name=java:flo15d_any
```

Comment: Of course, it is `null`. The value will be available until after the object is constructed not while it is being constructed. That being said, you are aware that you should be ditching this class and simply use `JdbcTemplate` as your code is flawed to being with?

Comment: so is there any way to get values of property file in testcon except jdbctemplate

Comment: It wil be there (if it is a spring managed instance!) after the object is constructed, it will **not** be available during construction even if it is a spring managed bean. Spring can only do things to object instances.